# Can I install and use Adobe CC applications without installing Adobe Creative Cloud

Tags: creative-cloud

I have full Adobe Apps plan.

I would like to use Adobe CC apps without using Adobe Creative Cloud.
At first glance, the situation is that Adobe is forcing the user to install an additional Adobe Creative Cloud.

The Adobe Creative Cloud application activates several processes that consume memory.
I don't need this application (eg. i can update individual programs manually).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Nope

Must have the Creative Cloud app to run Creative Cloud. It verifies subscriptions. You really *never* need to actually launch the Creative Cloud application itself, but it has to be present on the system. And that's what all those processes are doing.. verifying your subscription... checking CC libraries... etc. It's *not* merely about updates.

I'm not a huge fan of it either, but it seems to be a necessary evil.

Best way to get around it is to use CS6, if that's at all a possibility.